# How do you overlay a control over a grid that it is not in (xaml/wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid that serves as a drag/drop area between textboxes, however, placing it between them causes the textboxes to be displaced. How can I get it so that the drag/drop grid is behind the text boxes, instead of in between them?

The first grid is the drag/drop area and below is the code for the textboxes:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="20" AllowDrop="True" Background="White"
      DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" DragLeave="Grid_DragLeave" Drop="Grid_Drop" Tag="{Binding}"/>

<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,2" 
        Text="some text" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="5" />
</Grid>
```

[A picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYK0g.png), where the black boxes are the textboxes, and everything enclosed in the red is the grid area where things can be dragged and dropped.

Comment: could you print screen that?

Comment: The stuff I put in the textbox is just filler. The original is different and can't just be print screened. @FirstStep

Comment: Put all the drag/drop events on the Grid which contains the two textboxes. Or whatever their parent is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That doesn't give a continuous area in between and under the textboxes to drag things into. [Here's what I mean](http://i.imgur.com/ZEOkX1x.png) The red box represents the drag/drop area

Comment: Is the point to allow nearly half of the left text box to be dropped onto and only a quarter of the right text box, or is that just an inaccuracy in the picture?

Comment: @theK_S Oh, I get it. Do you need to drop on the area where the textboxes overlap the drop target grid, or is it OK just to accept drops on the parts of the target grid that aren't overlapped?

Comment: @AdamSills Inaccuracy in the picture, sorry for confusion

Comment: So are you trying to just drop between them or are they included? When I asked about inaccuracy it was an attempt for you to make it more accurate. Where *exactly* are you trying to drop?  Just between them or is it supposed to include the text boxes as well?

Comment: @EdPlunkett The textboxes should be able to be dropped anywhere within the red border, whether it overlaps with the textbox or not

Comment: That's an unusual requirement. I think that'll involve some custom handling to allow dropping only on part of the text boxes. Not terribly difficult, but it'll involve some codebehind stuff where you intersect some rectangles.

Comment: @AdamSills anywhere within the red border

Comment: Actually no rectangle intersection -- just give the textboxes and the droptarget grid the same handler, which converts the mouse coordinates to droptarget client coordinates and allows drop if it's within the droptarget's client area.

Comment: Normally when you want two things to be contained within the same space, you just do that. Put your drop target in the same container as your text boxes, but put it first in the document so the text boxes would sit atop it (so if it were to go in the grid containing the text box, give it a columnspan of 2, column 0). Then just size/margin the drop target accordingly to get your drop target where you want it.

Comment: I would have multiple columns with ColSpan.  Then some transparent control to take the drop.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Code behind is a mild bummer, especially referencing the droptarget by name. It would be easy to turn that into an attached property that you bind to the droptarget element, which would be convenient for use in templates etc. Anyhow you can't do drag/drop without codebehind, so there you are. Sometimes life gives you codebehind. Use it to, uh, make, um, lemons.

A lot of this XAML is just fussing around to make the elements overlap each other the way yours do. The `Grid.Column`/`Grid.ColumnSpan` stuff is important for the overlapping layout you have in mind.

Note that the TextBoxes use the `PreviewDragOver` event, not `DragOver`. `DragOver` wasn't being raised. Not sure if that's a bug or my faulty understanding, but a lot of people seem to have run into trouble getting `DragOver` to work with WPF `TextBox`.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid 
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="80,0,80,0"
        Height="80"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Drop="TextBox_Drop"
        DragOver="TextBox_DragOver"
        Background="DeepSkyBlue"
        x:Name="DropTargetGrid"
        AllowDrop="True"
        ></Grid>

    <TextBox 
        Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="40,40,10,40" 
        Drop="TextBox_Drop"
        PreviewDragOver="TextBox_DragOver"
        AllowDrop="True"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />

    <TextBox 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,40,40,40" 
        Drop="TextBox_Drop"
        PreviewDragOver="TextBox_DragOver"
        AllowDrop="True"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void TextBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //  Do whatever
}

private void TextBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var ptTargetClient = e.GetPosition(DropTargetGrid);

    if (ptTargetClient.X >= 0 && ptTargetClient.X <= DropTargetGrid.ActualWidth
        && ptTargetClient.Y >= 0 && ptTargetClient.Y <= DropTargetGrid.ActualHeight)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
}
```